# Installing Snap.js into Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to install `Snap.js` into my current Twitter Bootstrap theme but I'm a little lost, I don't want to lose my current styling for the desktop version, I just want to incorporate `snap.js` into my mobile version but I am not sure where to place certain files or what all I need to replace in my current markup.

[Here's the site](http://myadt.us/homesecurity.php)

If anything else is needed, please let me know and I'll add it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load the file only if the site is accessed with a mobile device. Something like

```
if (screen && screen.width > 480)
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"><\/script>');
```

Comment: Actually, there are two ways: inserting this `<script>` tag on each page or put just the into an `Javascript` file that is in use by all pages.